# Is the typical value (as consumed) refer to the product after cooking or before cooking?

Tags: noodles, egg-noodles

Looking at the Typical Values under Nutrition for [Morrisons Free Range Egg Noodles](https://groceries.morrisons.com/webshop/product/Morrisons-Free-Range-Egg-Noodles-/207852011), does the "(as consumed) per 100g" mean that 100g of uncooked noodles provides 107 calories when it is cooked, or 100g of cooked noodles provides 107 calories?

Comment: I fry them just using heat, no oil. So can you work out how many calories it would mean if 180g (measured before they are cooked) are cooked?

Answer (score 1):

Nutrition tables give the value for the product alone, as is, unless explicitly stated otherwise. Cereal sometimes describes a serving as Xg cereal plus Yg milk of a certain fat content, for example. But there should always be the “pure” values for 100g, as most food labeling laws require.

The [product description](https://groceries.morrisons.com/webshop/product/Morrisons-Free-Range-Egg-Noodles-/207852011?gclid=Cj0KCQiAs67yBRC7ARIsAF49CdWWPDuaCLsZgqq0P_iM4gvOCmBFVfihygm_9tXFTHQd25KtShTO9gEaAlz6EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) confirms this by explicitly stating **“as sold”**:

> A 1/4 pack (**as sold**) provides... Calories 110 5.5%, Sugar trace trace, **Fat 1.5g** 2.1%, Saturates 0.1g 0.5%, Salt trace trace of your guideline daily

If you check the table carefully, you’ll notice that for a 1/4 pack (slightly over 100g) the value for fat is 1.5g. This fits what the eggs in egg noodles would contribute, but is significantly less than what per the cooking instructions should be added for stir-frying.

If you want or need to calculate your calorie intake, weigh the product before your chosen preparation method and use basic maths to calculate the calories or other nutritional values. Any additions (like the aforementioned oil) need to be calculated separately.

Comment: So if I weighed 100g of these noodles before I cooked them then this provides 107 calories when cooked, forgetting any dressings or oil used to cook as I only use heat to cook these?

Comment: @EthanFairhurst Exactly. That’s how the nutrition labeling works.

Comment: I also found that the mass decreased after I cooked them? Does this mean that the calories would decrease from when I initially weighed due to the decrease in mass when I have cooked?

Comment: Unless you somehow removed anything with calories (water has no calories), no. You can’t evaporate calories.